# How to tell if a pointer is the pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++17

Consider this

```
template <class T>
inline constexpr bool found_to_be_array (T* specimen)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_array_v<T>) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    };
}
```

The question is in which context is this going to produce the reliable result?

Clarification: I can not change the footprint of this function. I have no answer, so let me post my findings here. Consider this:

```
int ia[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 };
int iam[3][3][3][3][3]{};

// returns false
auto is_array_1 = found_to_be_array(ia);

// returns true
auto is_array_2 = found_to_be_array(iam);
```

I am still researching this, but for multidimensional arrays, `found_to_be_array` works.

https://godbolt.org/g/ij73Z4

Comment: You cant.  All a pointer knows is the address it points to.

Comment: @NathanOliver not 100% correct, since OP is testing `T`, but accepting `T*`, case in point: https://godbolt.org/g/ruPVx3

Comment: @Frank I doubt that's what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @Frank Sure, that will work but what about `int x[3]; int* y = x; found_to_be_array(y);`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'pointer to array'? Is `y` in `int x[3], *y = x;` a pointer to array or not in your understanding?

Comment: @NathanOliver fully agreed, but if the question is "in which contexts does this work?", then "none" is not the right answer. That's all I meant.

Comment: You could check if the pointer points into *a particular array* by comparing the pointer's value to the addresses of the first and last items in that array; e.g. `bool is_ptr_pointing_to_array = ((ptr >= &arrayItem[0])&&(ptr < &arrayItem[NumItemsInArray]));`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner `<` is undefined for pointer arithmetic not in arrays, so that approach is somewhat circular I'm afraid.

Comment: @NathanOliver re: `what about int x[3]; int* y = x;` Here `y` is not a pointer to array, it is pointer to `int`, so it will return false as expected

Answer (score 5):

No this approach will not work. The parameter `specimen` has already decayed to a pointer type (or it might even have been a pointer all along); the metaprogramming technique used by `std::is_array` does not trace back in some way to the caller.

And besides, you're testing (unintentionally?) `T` rather than `T*` - but changing to the latter will not work.

Comment: `std::is_array_v<T*>` will never return true, as pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score 3):

> How to tell if a pointer is the pointer to array?

A pointer has type, which indicates what it points to. When it points to array, then the type of the pointer reflects this, for example:

```
int arr[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
auto x = &arr[0];
```

`x` in this case has the type of `int(*)[2]`- a pointer to array of 2 `int`s, in this case `{1,2}`. If you increase this pointer by 1 it will point to the next array of 2 `int`s, namely `{3,4}`. If you pass this pointer to your function, T will be deduced as `int[2]` and the result will be `true`;

In case of 1D array it is no different:

```
int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
auto x = &arr;
```

`x` type will be `int(*)[4]` and it will also work and the function will return `true`.

But if you pass array to your function and not the pointer, thus forcing it to decay to the pointer to its 1st element, the array information is lost, because the pointer is of type `int` now.

```
auto x = arr;
```

`x` here is of type `int *`, it is not pointing to array, it points to the first `int`, which is `1`. If you increase it by one it will point to the next `int`, which is `2` and so on. If this was a pointer to the array, it would point to the next byte after array end if you increase it by 1. Passing this pointer to your function would return `false`, because `int` type is not an array.

So to answer to your question, you can tell that the pointer is a pointer to array, because this information would be supplied in the pointer type.

> ```
> int iam[3][3][3][3][3]{};
> // returns true
> auto is_array_2 = found_to_be_array(iam);
> ```

`iam` decays to the pointer to its 1st element, basically you are testing if `iam[0]` is an array, which it is, and so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a non-null data-pointer points to an array-element, is always answered *maybe*.

Why, you ask?
The language explicitly allows you to treat any object as the single element of an array of one. Which is quite nifty when you need a sequence, want to copy a trivial object, or the like.

Thus, every pointer is one of:

1. a null-pointer,
2. a pointer to an element of an array,
3. a pointer to beyond an element of an array, or
4. invalid, meaning one of

   1. wild, meaning never initialized, or
   2. dangling, meaning the pointee's lifetime was ended.

And while you can differentiate between case 1 and 2 or 3, the rest would need analysis of potentially the complete history of the current run of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement that you can not change the function is weird/unreasonable.

If you can not change the function signature you can not detect how argument was produced(from ptr or array) because that information is lost.

Comment: It is not my requirement.